# MaterializeCSS:Open modal programmatically with options

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS and I can't open a modal programmatically and pass options at the same time.
Currently my code is:

first initialize modal, I know that HERE i can pass "options" but it's too early to me. I don't have those options available yet.

```
$('#mymodal').modal();
```

later, on button click, I open the modal and here is where i need to pass options

```
$('#mymodal').modal('open');
```

This code works properly:

```
$('#mymodal').modal({
    onOpenEnd: function(){
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

but it has to be called at init time, and this is the problem.

I need something like this, but it doesn't work

```
$('#mymodal').modal('open', {
    onOpenEnd: function(){
        alert('ok');
    }
});
```

Here is a complete example

```
function editBook(id) {
    $('#mymodal').modal('open', {
        onOpenEnd: function(){
            $.ajax({url: '/api/books/'+id})
            // ...
        }
    });
}

function editAuthor(id) {
    $('#mymodal').modal('open', {
        onOpenEnd: function(){
            $.ajax({url: '/api/authors/'+id})
            // ...
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mymodal').modal();
    $('#mybtn-book').click(function(){
        editBook($(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
    $('#mybtn-author').click(function(){
        editAuthor($(this).attr("data-id"));
    });
});
```

Thank you for any advice or workaround hint.

Comment: Could you detail the options that you need to pass? And the variety/number of these options?

Comment: Added a complete example. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you're trying to achieve. Spell it out as if you're explaining it to a child, step by step. When you say 'pass options', I thought you were referring to actually passing options to the init function (as described in the docs). There aren't many options to pass and they don't really do much, but are listed in full here: https://materializecss.com/modals.html. If you want to fill the modal with data, then that is a different thing altogether and can be done very easily with javascript.